# Can I reuse the same template to declare/define multiple things (without duplicating the template code)?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently writing a class that has some fancy templates to define some of its members, but some of those templates are exactly the same. Consider the following code (these are all class members):

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_convertible<int, T>::value>>
T get() const { return convert_self_to_int(); }

template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_constructible<T, string>::value>, typename = void>
T get() const { return convert_self_to_string(); }

template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_convertible<int, T>::value>>
operator T() const { return get<T>(); }

template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_constructible<T, string>::value>, typename = void>
operator T() const { return get<T>(); }
```

As you can see, I have a templated member function called `get`, which uses long and somewhat hard to read template code.

> This part is not essential for the question, but here's a brief explanation of all those fancy templates: `get` is a function which
>   can return data in one of two formats: if the template argument `T` is
>   a type into which an `int` can be converted, then the integral
>   representation of the data is returned (thus triggering the conversion
>   to the requested type, which we know is possible). If `T` is something
>   that can be constructed from a `string`, then the `string`
>   representation of the data is returned (again, triggering the
>   construction of `T` from a `string`). Any other type that does not
>   fall into these categories will simply cause a compile-time error,
>   which is exactly what this code is intended to do.

This class also has simple conversion operators defined, which are written in terms of `get`.

Now since these operators use the **exact same templates** as the corresponding definitions of `get`, can I somehow avoid duplicating all that nasty template code? Can I reuse a line of template code to define multiple things, making the code more readable?

Comment: you can use boolean operations in templates

Comment: You do know that defaulted template type arguments are not part of function signature and as such are not to be used in SFINAE overloads?

Comment: Well, I learned this kind of template overloading from stack overflow as well. Is it wrong then? But regardless, my question is still a valid one I think, even if my code has other problems I guess.

Comment: @adam10603, you either misunderstood what you've learned or you learned from the bad source.

Comment: How do I write this correctly then? I just want one definition for types that satisfy a certain criteria, another for types that satisfy another criteria, and trigger an error for types that satisfy neither. As far as I tested this, it works exactly like that.

Comment: @SergeyA OP has an extra `typename = void` in the two overloads. This works fine.

Comment: @Barry Yes, that is needed to avoid conflicting signatures. But I thought he meant it was still wrong regardless of that. Is it fine then?

Comment: @Barry, Adam - sorry, my bad. I completely missed the extra typename. I stand corrected, my comments are moot.

Comment: @SergeyA I really started questioning my methods there :D But to be fair, the extra typename is pretty much off the screen, so I don't blame you.

Comment: @Barry Oh, did I leave a `numericType` in there? Sorry. Thanks for editing it out. It's my own type, but I just replaced it with `int`s for the sake of the question. Forgot to replace one instance though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just have `operator T()` forward to `get<T>` using SFINAE. That way, you only need one `operator T()`:

```
template <class T, class = decltype(std::declval<ClassName>().get<T>())>
operator T() const { 
    return get<T>();
}
```

Also, for the multiple SFINAEs, instead of continually adding additional `typename=void`s you can change your `enable_if_t` to give you a defaulted `int`:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, int> = 0>
T get() const { return convert_self_to_int(); }

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<std::string, T>::value, int> = 0>
T get() const { return convert_self_to_string(); }
```

---

Now, that won't work in clang unfortunately so I'd simply suggest flipping the ordering. Have the `operator T()` be SFINAE-d:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, int> = 0>
operator T() const { return convert_self_to_int(); }

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<std::string, T>::value, int> = 0>
operator T() const { return convert_self_to_string(); }
```

And just have `get` forward along:

```
template <class T> T get() const { return operator T(); }
```

The advantage here is that we're not duplicating anything and the `std::is_convertible<>` type trait will work correctly - since `operator T()` is SFINAE-d. A test on `get<T>()` will fail, but that doesn't seem like something that is commonly testable.

Comment: Nice trick with paramter pack! Haven't seen it before, didn't think about it.

Comment: The solution you gave for the conversion operator gives me an error in Xcode, saying: Member access into incomplete type 'className'. And yes, I did replace className with the actual name. I'm confused. The trick with the template parameters is nice though :)

Comment: @adam10603 Hmm. Okay one min.

Comment: And clang doesn't like the parameter pack

Comment: Also, I tried the parameter pack thing with the template, but when I try to call a function defined with a template like that, it says the call is ambiguous :(

Comment: Didn't see your comment, but yeah, exactly. But anyway, I could do without that.

Comment: @adam10603 If you flip `operator T()` and `get()` (see update), it's a little better and works on both compilers. But still unsatisfactory.

Comment: It does work, but it's still very specific to this scenario, so I'm not accepting it just yet. I only brought up this code as an example for a more generic topic, although I wasn't very specific about that in the question, which I might address in a minute. But thanks anyway, you got all my upvotes.

Comment: @adam10603 By no means do you have to accept this answer. I don't even like this answer...